# Security flaw in Ubuntu remote desktop password

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, vnc

I'm hoping others can confirm this for me and then I can pass it along to the either Canonical or TightVNC

I remote into an ubuntu 12.10 desktop by using SSH Tunneling - that is from the desktop i'm on use putty to ssh into the remote desktop. Putty is configured to open ssh tunnel for the remote desktop port - e.g 5900

Then I use TightVNC viewer to VNC to localhost:5900 which then tunnels through ssh and connects me - that's a little lesson in SSH Tunneling but not the problem. Also i don't use port 5900 - tunneling is handy to avoid opening ports on your firewall but i digress...

The remote ubuntu desktop is configured to allow remote connections with a password. TightVNC prompts me for the password. Ubuntu accepts ANY password provided the password I enter starts with the actual password. Meaning, if my password is FOO - FOOBAR works, FOO1234 works etc.

Is this by design? Doesn't this dramatically reduce the effectiveness of a password.

Can anyone else reproduce this? I don't think the tunneling has anything to do with this. If  anyone else can remote into an ubuntu desktop using VNC and a password and try this i'd like to hear about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password is limited to 8 characters, and so is truncated by the viewer to that length.

> Although TightVNC encrypts VNC passwords sent over the net, the rest
>   of the traffic is sent as is, unencrypted (for password encryption,
>   VNC uses a DES-encrypted challenge-response scheme, where **the
>   password is limited by 8 characters**, and the effective DES key length
>   is 56 bits). [bold added]

From http://www.tightvnc.com/faq.php